# Change specific list item properties

Tags: html, css, selector

I am trying to change the background of the list item home to make sure that it has the hover properties even when it is non hovered. Even though I have mentioned it using a class, the text doesn't change.

HTML :

```
         <div id="header">
     <img id="logo" src="images/logo.jpg">
     <ul>
     <li> <a href="#">CONTACT</a> </li>
     <li> <a href="#">GALLERY</a> </li>
     <li> <a href="#">EVENTS</a> </li>
     <li> <a href="#" class="currentpage">HOME </a> </li>
     </ul>          
     </div>
```

CSS :

```
       #header ul {
        padding-top:1em;
          }

       #header ul li a.currentpage {
        color:white !important;
        background-color: #F96E5B !important;
       }

       #header ul li a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color:#676767;
        font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
        font-size: 1em;
        float:right;
        line-height: 3em;
        padding-right: 1em;
        padding-left:1em;
           }

          #header ul li a:hover{
      background-color: #F96E5B;
          }
```

http://ashwin931996.webege.com

Comment: Please post exactly what your question is. What's the HTML, what are you trying to do in the CSS?

Comment: I see one anchor has an id of `#selected` but there are no rules for this id in your css file.  There is a class called '.currentpage' in your css perhaps that is the class you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
<li>
<a  class="one" href="#">CONTACT</a>
</li>
<li>
<a class="two" href="#">GALLERY</a>
</li  class="one">
<li>
<a class="three" href="#">EVENTS</a>
</li>
<li>
<a class="four" href="#">HOME </a>
</li>
```

css

```
#header ul li a.one:hover
{background-color: #F96E99;
color: white;}
#header ul li a.two:hover
{background-color: #F96E22;
color: white;}
#header ul li a.three:hover
{background-color: #F96Eaa;
color: white;}
#header ul li a.four:hover
{background-color: #F96E55;
color: white;}
```

Demo ; http://jsfiddle.net/PbMg2/1/

You need to mention on separate class hover function. I hope this may be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your code from the page/link you posted, it looks like you want to change the a tag background color of the item you gave `id="selected"`

The css you want to target that is:

```
#header ul li a#selected {background:red /* or whatever color you want it */ }
```